# Adding an int to an array

Tags: java, arrays, int, addition

I'm having difficulty putting elements into an array after reading and parsing them from a file. The idea is that the text file I read in from has a question, then the next line is a number signifying which answer is correct. I parse the string to an int but then I cannot add the parsed int to my answers array. So my question is how do I add my int to my array answers? Here is my code

```
//here is how I define my arrays
 List<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();
 List<String> other = new ArrayList<String>();
 int[] answers = new int[questions.size()];

while (fScan.hasNextLine()) 
    {

        String line = fScan.nextLine();

    if (line.contains("?")) 
    {
        questions.add(line);
        String correctAnswer = fScan.nextLine();
        int rightAnswer = Integer.parseInt(correctAnswer);
        //here's where things go wrong

        answers.add(rightAnswer);

    } 
    else 
    {
        other.add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if parsing went wrong ?

Comment: Try printing out your rightAnswer instead of adding it. If that's fine, show how you define 'answers' array.

Comment: Due to the nature of how the file I read in is formatted, parsing should work unless there is some error with the code above

Comment: what is type of answers?

Comment: why don't you define ArrayList<Integer> ?

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. Overlooked the obvious answer haha, just had my heart set on an int array

Answer (score 0):

You should use ArrayList instead of array for your `answers`. Then you can add elements there like this, otherwise `.add` function will give you an error.

Alternatively, you can do `answers[i] = rightAnswer`, where `i` is the number of question you can add as a counter.

Answer (score 0):

Define answers as

```
ArrayList<Integer> answers=new ArrayList<>();
```

Also it will be good idea to consider `NumberFormatException` - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
   //here's where things go wrong
   answers[questions.size() - 1] = Integer.parseInt(correctAnswer);
```

or just use ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. Here's one:
Use `ArrayList answers = new ArrayList();` in your `answers` instead.
 In this case, you wont bother yourself converting a String into an integer since an ArrayList accepts an Object. Instead, you may use `answers.add(correctAnswer)` to append. However, if you want to fetch the values as a String you may use `answers.get(yourIndex).toString`.